# SlidingMenu in Child Activities Navigation Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to add left side slide menu inside my application but i am facing little trouble getting the slide menu to the following child activities of the fragment.

So far i have tried using [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) sliding menu example and when i got this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMFA2.jpg) now inside the "Find People" fragment class i have static data.

Find People (Parent Activity) on Button Click go to ---> Friends (Child Activity of Find People) on Button Click go to ----> Names (Child Activity of Friends)

I am trying to get the same sliding menu with the Child Activities also that i failed to achieve so far please can any one help me out

```
public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment {

public FindPeopleFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);

     Button btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.butto);

      btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Friends.class);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
  }
```

**Friends (Child Activity)**

```
public class Friends extends Activity {

Button btnNext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.friends_xml);
    btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNexts);

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Go to Names Child Activity


        }
    });

       }
     }
```

And Similarly **Names (Child Activity)**

How do i get the same slide menu in both the child activities (Friends & Names). Any idea ??
Plz help me out in this.
Code Snippet will be much helpful.
Thanks

Comment: So in that manner you can call new Fragment instead of call activities.

Comment: IS this issue solved??

Comment: yup it works fine now thx a lot dude !! (y)

Comment: Oh..Nice that.. Its very good.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Piyush Gupta said you need to call new Fragment instead of calling activities,

In Place of activity you need to use Fragment and move from one Fragment to next used this code

Instead of using Fragment element use Framelayout id of the fragment Xml

Replace ur code with this

```
public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment {

public FindPeopleFragment(){}

@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);

 Button btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.butto);

  btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        FragementDemo fd = new FragementDemo();


  android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction  ft =
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fd); // content_frame is your FrameLayout container
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
    }
});

return rootView;
}
  }
```

And your next child activity will extend Fragment not Activity like this :

```
   public class Friends extends SherlockFragment{



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragementdemo, container, false);

     // use button click code as used in FindPeopleFragment

    return rootView;


    }
```

}

Hope it works fine now for you!!